# Developing a vertical "UL" menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I´m developing a "UL" menu.
It is a vertical menu. Each link of this vertical menu has a submenu.
The menu elements have a onmouseout event, that removes the submenu.
The problem I´m facing is:

When I try to access the submenu, the onmouseout event is dispatched before I get into the submenu.
There are a space (margin) between the menu and submenu. I believe, that, when the mouse reach  this space, the "onmouseout" event is dispatched.
What can I do, so the "onmouseout" is not dispatched when the mouse is on this "space" between the menu and the submenu?

Thanks.

PS: I cannot post the code

Comment: You want the submenu UL's to be inside the main menu LI's. And you want to use mouseenter and mouseleave events (or just CSS `:hover`).

Comment: If you can't post *the code* post some *representative* code to reproduce the problem. it's hard to answer CSS/HTML/JavaScript questions with nothing to see.

Comment: Why can't you post code? You can anonymise it! Remove anything you don't want people to see, just so we've got something to work with.

Comment: I want the submenu at the right of the menu, and the structure of the menu needs a space between the menu and the submenu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do in such situations is to have a short `setTimeout` before removing the submenu, then clear that timeout when the submenu is moused over. This allows enough time for the mouse to get there, without affecting the visuals much, if at all.

Comment: I´m thinking to create this menu through divs.
If I´d create this menu through "UL", I´d have to add a settimeout to each submenu link, because they have margin-bottom, which gives me the same problem.
So, I think the solution is to make div container for the submenu with zIndex greater than its elements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple vertical menu done in CSS:

```
#menu {
    width: 100px;
    background: #ddd;
    cursor: default;
}

#menu > li {
    padding: 6px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    position: relative;
}

#menu > li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

#menu ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    left: 100px; top: 0;
    background: #eee;
}

#menu ul > li {
    padding: 6px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
}

#menu ul > li:hover {
    outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/3xguj/show/

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing the element in the inspector (using chrome or firebug) and reset all of the UL and LI css attributes. This would eliminate the spacing.

P.S. If you cannot post THE code, at least post SOME code which functions the same way and has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should structure your HTML, not just to solve your problem but also because it works semantically.

```
<ul>
    <li>Main Menu Item
    <ul>
        <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
        <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
        <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
    </ul></li>
    <li>Main Menu Item
    <ul>
        <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
        <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
        <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
    </ul></li>
</ul>
```

Note that the sub-menu is inside of the main menu item. This nesting gives it meaning and also means that while you are hovering over the sub menu, you are also still hovering over the main menu item that contains the sub menu.

You can test this with pure CSS such as this:

```
ul li ul {
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

See a rough demo of this in action on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/HFN3z/)